# If $3\sin 2A-\sin 4A=1$ then find the value of $\tan 2A+\tan 4A$ where $A$ be a positive acute angle

Tags: trigonometry

Given options $\tan 2A+\tan 4A=$
$(a) 1/2, (b) 0, (c) 1, (d) -1$

I have tried to solve the problem in the following manner-
$3\sin 2A-\sin 4A=1$
$\implies 3\sin 2A-2\sin 2A \cos 2A=1$
$\implies 3\tan 2A-2\sin 2A=\sec 2A$
$\implies \tan 2A={2\sin 2A+\sec 2A\over3}$
Now, $\tan 4A=\frac{2\tan 2A}{1-\tan^2 A}=\frac{(2/3)(2\sin 2A+\sec 2A)}{1-(1/9)(2\sin 2A+\sec 2A)^2}=\frac{6(2\sin 2A+\sec 2A)}{9-(2\sin 2A+\sec 2A)^2}$
So, $\tan 2A+\tan 4A={2\sin 2A+\sec 2A\over3}+\frac{6(2\sin 2A+\sec 2A)}{9-(2\sin 2A+\sec 2A)^2}$
But after this I am getting nothing. 
Can anybody solve this? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: Yea, it's just writing $X$ instead of $2A$ but how to proceed.

Comment: There is an error in the question. When $A \approx 0.363$, $3 \sin 2A - \sin 4A \approx 1$ but $\tan 2A + \tan 4A \approx 9.27$. The other acute value of $A$ also does not match up.

Comment: Could be https://socratic.org/questions/5a28bc087c01492229a0df91